# Mapped drive not reconnecting with other credentials on login (Server 2003)

Tags: group-policy, domain, mappeddrive, credentials

We have an old 2003 server (I know, we should have decommissioned this a long time ago), and we have a user who has an issue with a mapped drive.

The server and the user account are on our old domain, and they are mapping a drive to a server on the new domain, using the option to "Logon with other credentials". We are entering their new domain credentials, and the mapped drive works as expected.

However, upon log off and log back on, the mapped drive is connected, but they have lost access to folders they have permissions to. The only solution is to disconnect and remap the drive.

Could this be anything to do with NTLM settings in a group policy object, causing the credentials to not be saved upon a log off? I saw a mention of this in another article/forum post, but wasn't sure if it applied to us.

For note, the old domain is 2008 R2 functional level, and the new domain is 2012 R2 functional level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a VBS script in order to reconnect all devices on Logon.
You can do this putting this VBS script in the logon scripts of win2003 by setting in AD-users and computer>select user>profile>logon script.

This is just an example (You don't need to pass de credentials in the scripts after login phase):

On Error Resume Next

```
Dim objNetwork, strRemotePath1, strRemotePath2, strRemotePath3
Dim strDriveLetter1, strDriveLetter2, strDriveLetter3

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

' Drive letters and paths
strDriveLetter1 = "P:"
strRemotePath1 = "\\share\photo"



' Map network drives
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter1, strRemotePath1

' Quit wscript process
Wscript.Quit
```

I Hope it helps!

Comment: I did toy with the idea of a VBscript, but is there anyway to specify the credentials to use, as the drive needs to be connected with credentials different to the current users Windows login. Thanks

Comment: Come on... it under microsoft msdn..
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6(v=vs.84).aspx


strUsr = "username"
strPas = "password"
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strLocalDrive, strRemoteShare, strUsr, strPas

Comment: Great thanks, seems pretty straightforward. Will give it a go! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome!! :-)